# Why a program does not need to be re-compiled after changing a service program?

Tags: rpgle

I am trying to understand how a service program helps to reduce re-compilation effort. I read articles saying that unlike a module that is "bound by copy" into a program object, a service program is "bound by reference". Is this the reason why programs using the service program does not require re-compilation for changes to reflect?

If the program only has a reference to the service program, isnt it kind of a dynamic binding??

Also, what is the thing with a service program signature. When does it really change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several questions here, so let me look at binding. There are two different concepts here: bind by copy vs. bind by reference, and static vs. dynamic binding. The first only deals with where the code resides. Is it in the program (bind by copy), or somewhere external to the program itself (bind by reference). In both cases the call jumps to some other location to execute the code, so there is a reference or pointer being used in both cases, but in the bind by copy, the code is actually copied into the program object as well. The advantage of bind by reference as you opined, is that in the bind by reference scenario, the service program can be modified without recompiling all of the callers, and the new code immediately becomes available to any program that makes use of the service program.

Next, the difference between static and dynamic binding. According to computer science definitions, static binding happens at compile time, while dynamic binding happens at runtime. There is always a reference with both types. The question is when is that reference resolved. That said, procedure calls are static, and program calls are dynamic. Let's start with the basics:

```
**free
ctl-opt Main(testcallp);

dcl-pr Prog        ExtPgm('PGMA');
  parm1            Char(10) const;
  parm2            Char(10) const;
end-pr;

dcl-proc testcallp;

  callp Prog('1': '2');

end-proc;
```

This is a dynamic call. PGMA is not resolved at compile time, but at run time when the `callp` is executed. It may look like PGMA is resolved statically because it is only resolved once, but in fact, PGMA doesn't even have to exist when this code is compiled. Try it, the code will compile into a program object, but when that program is executed it can't find PGMA. So, dynamic binding must be happening.

Let's try it again with a procedure call:

```
**free
ctl-opt DftActGrp(*No) ActGrp(*New)
        Main(testcallp);

dcl-pr Proc        ExtProc('PROCA');
  parm1            Char(10) const;
  parm2            Char(10) const;
end-pr;

dcl-proc testcallp;

  callp Proc('1': '2');

end-proc;
```

This time the code compiles without syntax errors, but no program object is created because it failes on the bind step. The procedure PGMA cannot be found. Static binding. But wait, the RPG docs say you can call a procedure dynamically by using procedure pointers.

Let's try it:

```
**free
ctl-opt DftActGrp(*No) ActGrp(*New)
        Main(testcallp);

dcl-pr Proc        ExtProc(Procp);
  parm1            Char(10) const;
  parm2            Char(10) const;
end-pr;
dcl-pr Proca       ExtProc('PROCA');
  parm1            Char(10) const;
  parm2            Char(10) const;
end-pr;
dcl-s Procp        Pointer(*proc) Inz(%paddr(Proca));

dcl-proc testcallp;

  callp Proc('1': '2');

end-proc;
```

Once again the program compiles with no syntax errors, but gets hung up in the binding step because the procedure PROCA does not exist. Static binding. Even if we can change the actual procedure called at run time by swapping out the procedure that Procp points to, that procedure must exist at compile time because all of the procedures are statically bound into the program at compile time.

As for the binder source recommendations, I would only add a single recommendation to Barbra's answer, and that is to always add modules to service programs, and only reference service programs from program objects.

Note: There are API's that will let you resolve a procedure and bind it at run time, but those are well beyond the scope of this post.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that a call to a service program could also be considered "dynamic binding", but in general, the term "dynamic binding" is used for calls to programs.

When the signature of a service program changes depends whether you use binder source or not. If you create the srvpgm with no binder source (EXPORT(*ALL)), then the signature changes when there are new exports. If you create with binder source (EXPORT(*SRCFILE)), the the signature only changes if the signature specified by the STRPGMEXP command in the binder source changes.

The usual recommendation (and my recommendation) is to

- Use binder source
- Never change the signature
- Always add new exports at the end of the binder source

If the signature changes, then you do need to recompile the calling program, or at least you need to do the CRTPGM again if you already have a module.

But if the signature does not change, and the order of the exports does not change, you should not need to recompile the program to pick up the change in the service program.

But beware that you might need to end your job and start a new job before your program will see the change to the service program. The old version of the service program might already be activated into an activation group, so it might not use the new version of the service program.

Answer (score -1):

Service Programs would be much more fun if IBM would just add a LVLCHK Parameter to the CRTSRVPGM command instead of making it necessary to create a binding source only for that purpose.